# sqlite3, c++ connection, runnning queries, sqlite3_prepare_v2()

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have a situation where our connection with sqlite3 does not go through. This was my teammates code but he left the team and now I am trying to fix the problem in the code but I am fairly lost. The program compiles and I could only find the problem location with debugger tool in QtCreator. The debugger tool takes me to sqlite_prepare_v2 for the problem.

The debugger output is: (I'm posting this because it might be useful)

```
        nByte   84  size_t
        query   "SELECT username,password FROM users WHERE username='dilsizk' AND password='12345678'"  std::string
        return_matrix   <not accessible>    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>
        return_value    32745   int
        this    @0x7fe90ab23f5f DBHandler
            columns_    -1282717696 int
            db_connection_  0x740000800003f7da  sqlite3 * *
            log @0x7fe90ab23f5f Log
                count   -1064971727 int
            query_  0x401f0fc35bd08908  sqlite3_stmt * *
            return_matrix_  0xc748eb7501046e83  std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> *
        unusedSQL   "12345678"  char *
```

The code for the method is:

```
//query must be nul-terminated (ending in \0)
//if an error code is returned, method returns what it has processed to that point
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>* DBHandler::runQuery(std::string query) {
    //get byte size of query
    size_t nByte = std::strlen(query.c_str());
    //log
    log << "DBHandler: Query size is " + std::to_string((int)nByte) +" bytes";
    //make junk variable for potential unused sql
    const char **unusedSQL;
    //prepare the statement
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(*db_connection_,query.c_str(),(int)nByte,query_,unusedSQL);
    //log
    log << "DBHandler: Query formatted into prepared statement";
    //perform first step, grab return value
    int return_value = sqlite3_step(*query_);
    //log
    log << "DBHandler: First evaluation step completed";
    //check if done, and if it is because of an error or that there is only 1 row
    if(return_value != SQLITE_ROW) {
        //log
        log << "DBHandler: Query returns only 1 row";
        if(return_value != SQLITE_DONE) {
            //log
            log << "DBHandler: Error handling query, code 1";
            return (new std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>);
        }
    }
```

there is more to the method but I didn't wanna post the whole thing as the program cannot get to the steps after

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2(*db_connection_,query.c_str(),(int)nByte,query_,unusedSQL);
```

Also, let me provide the header for dbhandler.h for the variables.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include "log.h"

#include <iostream>

/* Class to handle interaction with the local test database in the /db_tools directory.  Run ./newDB.sh in that directory prior to use. */
class DBHandler {

public:
    /* Constructor to create DBHandler object. */
    /*!
     * This object should ALWAYS be destroyed by its destructor when use is done.  The constructor only opens a connection to the local database.
     */
    DBHandler();
    /* Destructor to prevent memory leaks from this object. */
    /*!
     * Important that this is called, as it is otherwise vulnerable to causing multiple memory leaks.
     */
    ~DBHandler();
    /* Runs a query to the database and returns the output in a formatted vector. */
    /*!
     * This method formats the query, passed as a string, into a prepared statement to be processed.
     * \param query The query to the database. Must be nul-terminated (ending in \0) with no whitespace between the end of the query and the zero-terminator.
     * \return Returns a vector, where each index holds a vector per column, whose 0 index is the column name and all following indices are entries in order of their row.
     */
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>* runQuery(std::string query);

private:
    Log log;
    sqlite3** db_connection_;   /** Database connection object. **/
    sqlite3_stmt** query_;  /** Prepared statement object. **/
    int columns_;   /** Number of columns in the prepared statement after 1 step. **/
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>* return_matrix_;  /** Pointer to the matrix containing the evaluation of the prepared statement. **/
    /* Fills the return matrix with the names of the columns in the prepared statement. */
    void fillColName();
    /* Fills each column vector in the return matrix with the entries from the most recent step of the prepared statement. */
    void fillRow();
};
```

I am sorry for a lot of the text but I thought that these outputs would useful while trying to solve the problem.

Please let me know if there is anything else that I can provide or if my question is missing something. Im fairly new to the website. Just trying to be able to ask well formatted questions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html), the last parameter of `sqlite_prepare_v2` is the location of a pointer which receives the rest of the SQL statement (as prepare only compiles the first sql statement in the query).

Your code is passing an uninitialised variable as that parameter, so when `sqlite_prepare_v2` tries to change the value of the pointer, it overwrites some random memory.

Use something like this instead:

```
const char *unusedSQL = NULL;
//prepare the statement
sqlite3_prepare_v2(*db_connection_,query.c_str(),(int)nByte,query_,&unusedSQL);
```

Also the fourth parameter to `sqlite3_prepare_v2` is supposed to be a pointer to a variable that will receive the compiled statement, your code is passing `_query` which is a member variable of your class, but you haven't shown how it is initialised. I suspect this has the same problem as the `unusedSQL`.

You should change the declaration to

```
sqlite3_stmt* query_
```

and pass through a pointer to the `query_` parameter:

```
const char *unusedSQL = NULL;
query_ = NULL;
//prepare the statement
sqlite3_prepare_v2(*db_connection_,query.c_str(),(int)nByte, &query_, &unusedSQL);
```

Also note: `sqlite3_prepare_v2` has a return value - you should check it to see if everything worked.

Comment: Yes, changing these according to your suggestions worked! I was able to figure it out but you explained it much better than I would be able to. Thank you.